# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable-how can i solve this error

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
models = [dtree,bagging,bagging_wt,rf,rf_wt,dtree_estimator,bagging_estimator,rf_estimator]

acc_train = []
acc_test = []
recall_train = []
recall_test = []
precision_train = []
precision_test = []


for model in models:
    
    j = get_accuracy_score(model,False)
    acc_train.append(j[0])
    acc_test.append(j[1])
       
    k = get_recall_score(model,False)
    recall_train.append(k[0])
    recall_test.append(k[1])
   
    l = get_precision_score(model,False)
    precision_train.append(l[0])
    precision_test.append(l[1])
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-215-b1cbc190be6f> in <module>
     12 
     13     j = get_accuracy_score(model,False)
---> 14     acc_train.append(j[0])
     15     acc_test.append(j[1])
     16 

TypeError: NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Obviously the `get_accuracy_score()` function is returning a `None` value. This might have happened because you forgot to write a return statement there. Unless you show us the function's code, that can't be fixed by us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to familiarize yourself with how Python traceback works.
All the information you need is in the exception itself.

It tells you that the object is not subscriptable in lines 14 and 15. You are trying to access indexes in an object that does not allow it or does not have it (in this case, `None`).

And as @edusanketdk said, your function `get_accuracy_score` is at fault here as it returns `None` rather than a container object.